# what is the difference between declaring multiple foreign keys at once or declaring them individually?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Order_List that contains a list of orders.  Each column contains a foreign key that references the primary key of an order in the order table.  My question is, what is the best way to declare these foreign keys.  Using MySQL Workbench I found two ways...

Method #1

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'mydb'.'Order_List' (
    'idOrder_List' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    'orderID01' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    'orderID02' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    'orderID03' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    'orderID04' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ('idOrder_List') ,
    INDEX 'fk_Order_List_1' ('orderID01' ASC, 'orderID02' ASC, 'orderID03' ASC, 'orderID04' ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_Order_List_1'
      FOREIGN KEY ('orderID01' , 'orderID02' , 'orderID03' , 'orderID04' )
      REFERENCES 'mydb'.'Order' ('idOrder' , 'idOrder' , 'idOrder' , 'idOrder' )
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Method #2

```
  CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'mydb'.'Order_List' (
    'idOrder_List' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    'orderID01' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    'orderID02' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    'orderID03' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    'orderID04' INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ('idOrder_List') ,
    INDEX 'fk_Order_List_1' ('orderID01' ASC) ,
    INDEX 'fk_Order_List_2' ('orderID02' ASC) ,
    INDEX 'fk_Order_List_3' ('orderID03' ASC) ,
    INDEX 'fk_Order_List_4' ('orderID04' ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_Order_List_1'
      FOREIGN KEY ('orderID01' )
      REFERENCES 'mydb'.'Order' ('idOrder' )
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_Order_List_2'
      FOREIGN KEY ('orderID02' )
      REFERENCES 'mydb'.'Order' ('idOrder' )
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_Order_List_3'
      FOREIGN KEY ('orderID03' )
      REFERENCES 'mydb'.'Order' ('idOrder' )
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_Order_List_4'
      FOREIGN KEY ('orderID04' )
      REFERENCES 'mydb'.'Order' ('idOrder' )
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The first method combines the declaration.  The second method splits it up.  Which one is better?  Are there any inherent weaknesses to one over the other?  Thanks!

Comment: Will all of the `orderID` columns always be used?

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. We don't use bbcode tags here. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the same FK.

- One ensures that the *combination* of the 4 columns in any OrderList row exist in a single row row in `'mydb'.'Order'`
- The other ensures that the 4 column values in any OrderList row exist *independently* of the others in some `'mydb'.'Order'` row

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first example you have **one** `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (made of four columns), while in your second example you have **four** `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

In your first example, the four columns refer to the same column in the `Order` table, so you'll be able to only store combinations of 4 **identical** order ids. So, it is no more useful than a simple one-column reference.

If you use the second example, you'll be able to store any combination of 4 orders in the `OrderList` table.

Answer (score 0):

That is one god awful way of doing an order list. You should have an order list table, and a order list entries table. That way you don't have just 4 items in the list, and only a single index/foreign key from the order list entries table to the orders table.